# Is it possible to use 'responsive' images in/with a DIV background-image tag?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I'm looking to use a selection of Thumbnails that are loaded into my site from a database at different sizes (all within a Masonry grid)

Normally I would simply use `background-image:url(image.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%:` but I'm trying to be a little more bandwidth conscious with specific image file sizes. I also want to target a specific crop for mobile browsers using a portrait orientation.

Is it possible to use the features of the `<picture>`, namely `media="(min-width: 40em) and (orientation: portrait)"` while using the `background-image` property?

Or should I instead use the `img` or `picture` tags?

Comment: No you can't, but you can use media query to load different sized background images (more browser now only load images when a certain media query is valid) ... or you need the img/picture solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the image tag, along with media queries. That will solve the problem and you will be able to send smaller versions in case a smaller picture size is needed. If bandwidth is of serious concern here, then you might consider to do media-queries only based on screen size.